# iisnode module is unable to start the node.exe process

Tags: node.js, iis, iisnode

Hi I am trying run node on IIS as a subdirectory of an existing website.

https://somewebsite/node like so

1. Download and installed to the windows machine https://github.com/azure/iisnode/wiki/iisnode-releases

And it works but when I go to a specific js file I got this message, not sure what to do.

The iisnode module is unable to start the node.exe process. Make sure the node.exe executable is available at the location specified in the system.webServer/iisnode/@nodeProcessCommandLine element of web.config. By default node.exe is expected in one of the directories listed in the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Added the following code in web.config file and it works!

```
<iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" />
```

Comment: as iisnode installation required to nodejs installed at location "Program Files (x86)" for me it work by a little change on the path:

<iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" />

Comment: very useful answer and it's true that you have to guide IISNODE for node.exe path

Answer (score 1):

You should consider two important points.

1. Check the path of node.exe on the "system.webServer/iisnode".
2. Check you did install nodejs from the [official site](https://nodejs.org). You have to able to find node.exe in the default path: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe

I recommend you read [this article](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004195813-Node-js-application-is-not-working-on-Plesk-for-Windows-The-iisnode-module-is-unable-to-start-the-node-exe-process) for setting the right path of the node on the "system.webServer/iisnode".

Answer (score 0):

I had working node 6x and iisnode. When i installed node 8x for Angular 7 on my Windows 8, I got the same error as a result of rest API call as in question

For me, just needed to add the path to node.exe in the Windows environment variables and iisnode worked as before

Answer (score 0):

In windows Server

first you should check environment paths

`C:\> Path`

remove all previous installation and uninstall nodejs from other package managers

then download 64-bit msi installer from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org) / [download page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

then install again

and restart server

then you can Comment this line again In Web.Config

```
  <!--     
    
    One more setting that can be modified is the path to the node.exe executable and the interceptor:
    
    <iisnode
      nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;%programfiles%\nodejs\node.exe&quot;" 
      interceptor="&quot;%programfiles%\iisnode\interceptor.js&quot;" />
    
    -->
```

Answer (score -1):

By setting the values in C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\configuratio\web.config is not always fixing the issue . Please follow the below steps and try to set in IIS server level.

1. Select IIS server and open Configuration editor https://www.screencast.com/t/SWcy4C5m
2. Select the section system.webServer/iisnode and set the nodeProcessCommandLine value to node.exe full path. https://www.screencast.com/t/e8N6MFeWEueS

This fixed my issue. Hope this will be helpful to someone.